# MYSQL : Mix data from 3 tables and JOIN with another table

Tags: mysql, join, union

I've searched a long time to find a query on stackoverflow and google that look like to mine, but haven't found what i want. Tried many queries too, but i'm not enough skilled with SQL :(

```
Posts (id, title, url)
Imgs (id, title, url)
Zaps (id, title, url)

Comments(id, T_id, date, user, comment, from)
```

---

```
T_id = ids from Posts, Imgs, Zaps

from = contain text from wich table the data come from ("post", "img", "zap")
```

---

The table Comments contains all the mixed comments from the 3 tables.
I'm trying to get this output :

```
Comments.id, Comments.user, Comments.comment, Comments.from, title, url
```

The listing of the last comments with the title and url of the table which it comes from.

I know my schema is somewhat fucked up, its in production and i cannot really alter it.

If someone can help me, i'll really appreciate it.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by _the last comments_? Do you only want the one or _n_ most recent comments for each table?

Comment: It might help if you posted a sample set of rows for each table and a sample of the desired output, but I think I understand aside for my previous question.

Comment: Can you explain the columns of the tables? How they belongs together?

Comment: The last comments, whatever the table they come from.
But, the response from @Chad seems to works, i've added an order by and limit at the end of the query, it return what i'm expecting.

Comment: @Jens like i said, my schema is not really optimized or anything, but look at the response given by Chad and the joins it use, it's right way to link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the T_id/from columns in comments to the proper unique id in the right table.

```
select c.id, c.user, c.comment, c.from, t.title, t.url
from Comments c, Posts t
where c.T_id=t.id and c.from='post'
union
select c.id, c.user, c.comment, c.from, t.title, t.url
from Comments c, Imgs t
where c.T_id=t.id and c.from='img'
union
select c.id, c.user, c.comment, c.from, t.title, t.url
from Comments c, Zaps t
where c.T_id=t.id and c.from='zap'
```

Comment: The `UNION ALL` set operator usually has better performance than `UNION`, since it avoids the extra step of identifying duplicates to be removed from the resultset.

Comment: I don't know why... i wasn't far from this query but i managed to fail it... this query works, but i replaced the old joins with "left join" ones, and it's all good, thanks !